# Write and read to a register created in FPGA by verilog at the same time

Tags: fpga

What will happen if I read and write a register both at the posedge of the clock cycle? I encountered this question while learning a RISC-V pipeline implementation which uses the technique called double bump to avoid this question. I wonder why this is necessary to split the write and read of an register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved. Because 5-stages pipeline I designed launch instruction at posedge, and at negedge the result in the WT stage can be read into register file. Thus it is just a way to save a stall. I misunderstood that at first.